# Magento: add a payment fee when using PayPal Express

Tags: magento, paypal

In Magento 1.6.0 I want to add a 2% payment fee when the customer selects PayPal Express payment.
Unfortunately, Magento's PayPal module doesn't provide an option for fees.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
aeno

Comment: I think this sould be re-opened and moved to [magento.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we had the same problem and decided to buy an extension for that. Much faster and cheaper then develop this on your own.

http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-surcharge.html

very simple install and setup.

I highly recommented this extension.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for that - seems to suit perfectly :)

Comment: It misses tax on surcharge

Comment: Work perfect and good code!!

Answer (score 5):

This one is for free: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-payment-fee-3194.html. Also works on other standard payment methods.

Comment: It only misses tax on surcharge

Comment: Not work with magento CE 1.7

Answer (score 1):

We also had this problem, however, we bought this: http://www.mageworx.com/multi-fees-magento-extension.html
Fooman Surcharge and Mageworx MultiFees are pretty much the same. We decided to get MultiFees, as  Fooman Surcharge has 1 year of updates and Mageworx MultiFees has free updates and lifetime support.